# How to use Gallery View in Android, but on another page

Tags: android, gallery, android-context

I've got 2 layout files in res/layout folder: main.xml and page2.xml. 
In the main.xml I've got welcome info and button which starts

```
setContentView(R.layout.page2);
```

to change to page2.xml.

It worked fine till I decided to add Gallery view in page2.xml.

When I set from begining ContentView to page2 like below it's ok.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page2); 
    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);       
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

But when I call main.xml first to show may start page...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);       
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

the app returns error. 
I know that the problem is with Context in line

```
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

but I completely don't know how to pass right context or solve it in another way (but I don't want to have all layout in one xml file).

Comment: What error (exception) is raised?

Comment: You say that a button opens page2.xml with setContentView but later you show as example two onCreate. Not clear to me if you have one or two Activity.

Comment: On the screen I just see that it was forced to quit. I was trying to check smth more in debugger, but cant find any detailed error code. And I have one Activity. I don't use Intent to start new activity, just set another ContentView after button is pressed: public void buttonPressed (View target) {setContentView(R.layout.page2);         }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your explanation (logs never hurt), but I think you're getting a null pointer exception because `gallery` is not defined in your `main.xml`. There are two solutions for your problem:

1. Split your two "pages" into two activities. This is a much more natural way of dealing with things. Try rotating your phone/emulator and you'll see what I mean. When the user clicks on the button or whatever, call `startActivity()` and then call `finish()`, so your welcome activity is not left hanging about.
2. The problem is that `findViewById()` acts on whatever is "visible" in the activity right now. Since you did `setContentView(main)`, your `Gallery` will not be there. Try "getting" the gallery only after you make the call to "change pages" (`setContentView(R.layout.page2);`).

However, I would strongly advice you go with the first option.

Comment: Thx a lot. Two Activities are working properly. I thought simple layout change could stay with one activity. I tried also to move setting adapter after changing view: 'public void buttonPressed (View target) {setContentView(R.layout.page); g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));}' but the error stays. So I'd use option one :)

Comment: Great! Like I said, it's much more natural because otherwise you'd have to also save the state (hasSeenWelcome), etc etc. Its just easier to separate them out.